# Eloquent many to many self/meta relationship $this->hasMany($this)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

So I am working on a project in Laravel 4, and I am wondering how to do a many to many relationship on a single Model. I think comments should be able to belong to other comments (replies) Or at the very least replies should be able to have many replies.

I *think* that the way I would build the model would be:

```
Class Comment extends Eloquent {
    public function comments() {
        // assuming my comments table has an $id column and a second $comment_id table
        // do I even need to specify the column name?             
        return $this->hasMany('Comment', 'comment_id'); 
    }
    public function comment() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Comment');
    }
}
```

Where can I look for more documentation about this, or what is the Laravel way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: I would name them differently (maybe `replies` and `parent`), in which case you'd need the column name in both cases, but from a glance this looks like it should be fine.

Comment: but if I wanted to have nested replies wouldn't i need to do the same thing with replies anyway - I would just be pushing the same problem lower down the chain, or are you suggesting i have two columns parent_id & child_id?

Comment: A "has-many" relation means that all related objects belonging to the entity are identified because they have a column mapping to our object. In this example, you would only have a `parent_id` column. All children are then identified as they have the current object's ID as `parent_id`.